# unique results from prolog

Tags: prolog

Is there a easy way to make a query in prolog only return each result once?

for instance I'm trying something like:

```
deadly(Xn) :- scary(X), Xn is X - 1, Xp is X + 1, not(safe(Xn)), safe(Xp).
deadly(Xp) :- scary(X), Xn is X - 1, Xp is X + 1, not(safe(Xp)), safe(Xn).

deadly(X).
```

and getting

```
X = 5

X = 5

X = 5

X = 5

....
```

Not to usefull for me.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that you can do is to apply `setof/3` to the predicate that generates the solutions. But note that `setof/3` is implemented by applying `sort/2` to the result delivered by `bagof/3` (at least this is the case in SWI-Prolog). So, if your solution generator goes on forever, then `setof/3` will never be applied...

So I would say that try to program so that duplicates are not generated, i.e. by using the cut (!) where it makes sense.

Comment: If I remembercorrectly, setof is only useful if the query has a finite solution size, and it knows that it's done. Otherwise, it could just keep getting a 5, saying, Nope, already got that, and looking again, and getting ANOTHER 5... infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly there is a predicate solutions (or similar, it's been a while since I programmed Prolog) which collects unique solutions in a list.

**Edit:** `setof/3` is the one I was thinking of. Thanks, Kaarel.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to memoize solutions.

```
:- dynamic seen/1.

% Call this always before calling deadly_wrapper/1
clear_seen :-
    retractall(seen(_)).

% This wrapper calls deadly/1 but remembers
% the solution using assert/1, and fails
% if the solution has been "seen" before.
deadly_wrapper(X) :-
    deadly(X),
    (
        seen(X)
    ->  
        fail
    ;
        assert(seen(X))
    ).  


% This is for testing.
deadly(1).
deadly(1).
deadly(1).
deadly(5).
deadly(1).
deadly(1).
```

In case your Prolog supports tabling, then it gets even simpler.
Example file:

```
:- table deadly/1.

deadly(1).
deadly(1).
deadly(5).
deadly(1).
deadly(5).
```

Example execution with [XSB](http://xsb.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xsb
[xsb_configuration loaded]
[sysinitrc loaded]

XSB Version 3.2 (Kopi Lewak) of March 15, 2009
[x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu; mode: optimal; engine: slg-wam;
 scheduling: local; word size: 64]

| ?- [deadly_tab].
[Compiling ./deadly_tab]
[deadly_tab compiled, cpu time used: 0.0100 seconds]
[deadly_tab loaded]

yes
| ?- deadly(X).

X = 5;

X = 1;

no
| ?-
```

Comment: I would say "memoize", rather than "memorize".

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without more of your code, but you're probably looking for the cut operator (`!`).  If you want to post the *definition* of `foo`, I (or someone else who follows) may be able to give a detailed/specific answer.

Comment: every time I've used ! it has totally stopped evaluation and I do want every value that prolog is finding, but only once per value. (I'll try and cut down my case)

Comment: It's a matter of when and where to use it.  Saying "never come back here again" has a wildly different meaning coming before or after the first capture of the data.