# Duplicate solutions

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I have a problem trying to get some code that returns unique answers to my query. For example, defining

```
stuff(A,B,C) :- A=C ; B=C.
morestuff([],[],[]).
morestuff([A|AA],[B|BB],[C|CC]) :- stuff(A,B,C), morestuff(AA,BB,CC).
```

then running

```
morestuff([A,A],[A,B],[a,b]).
```

gives the output:

```
A = a
B = b ? ;

A = a
B = b ? ;

yes.
```

As you can see the two solutions are the same. Is there a way of just getting PROLOG to return the unique solutions, i,e. give the output:

```
A = a
B = b ? ;

yes.
```

Comment: +1 for a prolog question. I don't see them too often here.

Comment: This question has been already discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724358/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use

```
| ?- setof(sol(A,B),morestuff([A,A],[A,B],[a,b]),L).
L = [sol(a,b)] ? 
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know is to use `findall/3` to generate all results, then remove duplicates yourself. (Barring the most obvious solution - avoid algorithms that overgenerate; but then, in many cases you can't do that.)